# kotlin error - suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

Tags: kotlin

I'm brand new in Kotlin, basically I'm following a guide to create this app but was done with older Kotlin version.

My problem is here in my java/MainActivity.kt file

This is the function I'm trying to call

```html
    private suspend fun getTokenAsync(): String {
        return getToken()
    }
```

and here is the caller

```html
private suspend fun handleLoadWebView() {
        
        //some code here.....

        var token: String

        runBlocking{
            val resp = async { getTokenAsync() }
            token = resp.await()
            val jsonResp = JSONObject(token)
            loadWebView(exampleActivity, jsonResp.getString("access_token"), subdomain, content, options)
        }
    }
```

but getting the error in this line
**val resp = async { getTokenAsync() }**

Comment: Are you sure about the java tag ?

Comment: In which line the error occurs? I don't see any highlight.

Comment: question updated

Comment: If you’re new to Kotlin, Coroutines are not the easiest thing to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really messed things up a bit here.

First of all, both functions are suspendable, so you don't need `runBlocking()` there. In fact, you should never (?) use `runBlocking()` inside a suspend function. Second, running `async()` just to immediately `await()` on it doesn't make too much sense. This is almost the same as invoking `getTokenAsync()` directly. Also, the name of `getTokenAsync()` may be misleading as suspend functions are actually invoked synchronously.

Your whole `handleLoadWebView()` could be replaced with simple:

```kotlin
private suspend fun handleLoadWebView() {
    val jsonResp = JSONObject(getTokenAsync())
    loadWebView(exampleActivity, jsonResp.getString("access_token"), subdomain, content, options)
}
```

However, there may be more things going on here, so I don't say this is a fully working example.

Comment: It’s also suspicious that `getTokenAsync()` exists at all. There’s no reason to create a function simply to call another function with almost the same name. Makes you wonder if `getToken()` is a non-suspend function and someone thought wrapping it in a suspend function would accomplish something, like making it capable of suspending.